# Why is eip not being overwritten with the shellcode I am overflowing with?

Tags: c, linux, buffer-overflow, shellcode, eip

So I am having to do a buffer overflow for an assignment and I feel like I am very close. I must note that my teacher has set up a VM for us to use in which if we are able to get shellcode into the return address of the stack, it will execute there on the stack. I do not need to do a loop back into my buffer or any of that. I am of the understanding that the register I am wanting to overwrite and put my shellcode in is `eip`. I got that from info from here https://greyhat.gatech.edu/wiki/index.php?title=Stack_Buffer_Overflow

I have figured out that if I fill my buffer, `s1[64]` with 72 characters, I can get a seg fault: `Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000 in ?? ()` And when I have gdb print out the value of the registers I get:

```
 ebx            0xb7fc8000       -1208188928
 esp            0xbffff600       0xbffff600
 ebp            0x0      0x0     
 esi            0x0      0
 edi            0x80484c0        134513856
 eip            0x0      0x0     <------ Clearly i've messed up eip
```

If I fill my buffer with one less character,aka 71, the program executes sucessfuly, so I feel like 72 has to be a magic number somehow. So I have then tried to fill `s1` with 72 filler characters followed by my shellcode. I get a different segfault this time:

`Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x080486f5 in main () at badcopyTester2.c:61`   and gdb reveals that `eip` is filled with `0x080486f5` Why/How did `eip` get this value over it? Shouldn't it my shellcode in there? Also, no matter what I put at the end of my 72 filler characters, `eip` is always filled with that same `0x080486f5`.  Both the input of 
`AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA`  and

`AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\xeb\x18\x5e\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07\x89\x76\x08\x89\x46\x0c\xb0\x0b\x8d\x1e\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\xe8\xe3\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68` give that exact same segment fault.

Again, I feel like I'm very close as I found how to get `eip` cleared but am stuck past that. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Inspect the assembly code you want to hack. If there are gs or fs registers somewhere, the code is protected by canary mechanisms.

Comment: Well I just copied the shellcode that my instructor used in another simple example in class, so I believe it should work as it did then

Comment: And the code I am using to do the overflow was specifically written to be vulnerable to this attack

Comment: And you are sure that you attempt to overwrite eip pushed on stack?

Comment: @icbytes (I'm in the same class with the same issue) here's a link to what we're working with. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jj83t77geqcaj1w/AADemQoUudjSeGgFqJscIj3ya?dl=0

Comment: Which kernel is in use?